# Help with graphing an inequality?

Tags: inequality

Looking at this question, and I'm unsure of how to do it properly. I'm trying to graph y≥3x+4 if x<2 and y≥-3.
Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image: Geogebra]
Using Geogebra, which is a really neat piece of software